Volume inside a cardioid-based cylinder and a sphere
I'm trying to compute the volume inside both the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ and the cylinder whose generatrices are parallel to the $Z$ axis and whose intersection with the plane $z = 0$ is the cardioid $\rho = \frac{a}{2} (1 + \cos \theta)$ ($a>0$).
Now, this seems a fairly straightforward question, since the interior of the cylinder can be described by using cylindrical coordinates as
$$\left\{(\rho \cos \theta, \rho \sin \theta, z) : \begin{matrix} -\pi < \theta < \pi \\ 0 < \rho < \frac{a}{2}(1+\cos \theta) \\ z \in \mathbb{R} \end{matrix} \right\}.$$
The points inside the sphere are those satisfying $(\rho \cos \theta)^2+(\rho \sin \theta)^2 + z^2 < a^2,$ that is, $\rho^2 + z^2 < a^2,$ so the region $V$ whose volume we want to compute is
$$V = \left\{(\rho \cos \theta, \rho \sin \theta, z) : (\rho, \theta, z) \in E \right\},$$
with $E = \{(\rho, \theta, z) : -\pi < \theta < \pi, \, 0 < \rho < \frac{a}{2}(1+\cos \theta), \, \rho^2+z^2<a^2\}.$
Therefore, the volume is
$$ \text{vol}(V) = \iiint_V dx \,dy \,dz =  \iiint_E \rho \, d\rho \, d\theta \, dz,$$
and according to Fubini's theorem this integral becomes
$$ \begin{align} \text{vol}(V) &= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_0^{\frac{a}{2}(1+\cos \theta)} \int_{-\sqrt{a^2-\rho^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-\rho^2}} \rho \, dz \, d\rho \, d\theta =\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_0^{\frac{a}{2}(1+\cos \theta)} 2\rho \sqrt{a^2-\rho^2} d\rho \, d\theta \\ &=- \int_{-\pi}^\pi  \left[ \frac{2}{3} \left( a^2 - \left( \frac{a}{2}(1 + \cos \theta)\right)^2 \right)^{3/2} - \frac{2}{3} a^3 \right]d\theta \end{align}$$
The problem is I haven't been able to evaluate this last integral, because the exponent $3/2$ complicates finding an antiderivative. So the question is: can this integral be evaluated analytically? Or can one set up the problem differently so as to avoid such an ugly integral? Or have I made any other mistake?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

What you've done thus far is correct. There is an elementary integral hidden behind a wall of substitutions:
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{a^3}{12} \left(8 - (3 - 2\cos\theta - \cos^2\theta)^{3/2}\right) \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{a^3}{12} \left(16\pi - J\right) \\
&= \boxed{\frac{a^3}{36} \left(48\pi - 34\sqrt2 - 42 \operatorname{arsinh}1\right)}
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
J &= 2 \int_0^\pi \left(3 - 2\cos\theta - \cos^2\theta\right)^{3/2} \, d\theta & \rm symmetry \\
&= 2 \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^\tfrac\pi2 \left(3 + 2\sin\theta - \sin^2\theta\right)^{3/2} \, d\theta & \theta\to\theta+\frac\pi2 \\
&= 2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(3-t)^{3/2} (1+t)}{\sqrt{1-t}} \, dt & \theta=\arcsin t \\
&= 32 \int_0^\infty \frac{\left(1+2u^2\right)^{3/2}}{\left(1+u^2\right)^4} \, du & t=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2} \\
&= 256\sqrt2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh^4v}{\left(2 + \sinh^2v\right)^4} \, dv & u=\frac1{\sqrt2}\sinh v \\
&= 32\sqrt2 \int_0^1 \frac{\left(1-w^2\right)^3 \left(1+w^2\right)^4}{\left(1+w^4\right)^4} \, dw & v=2\operatorname{artanh}w \\
&= 16\sqrt2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi4 \left(\sqrt{\cot x} + \sqrt{\tan x}\right) \cos^3(2x) \, dx & w=\sqrt{\tan x} \\
&= 256\sqrt2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi4 \frac{\sin^3x \cos^4x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2x}} \, dx & x\to\frac\pi4-x \\
&= 32 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \sin^3y \left(1+\cos^2y\right)^{3/2} \, dy & y=\arcsin\left(\sqrt2\,\sin x\right) \\
&= 32 \int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}1} \cosh^4z \left(1-\sinh^2z\right) \, dz & z=\operatorname{arsinh}(\cos y) \\
&= \int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}1} \left(14 + 17\cosh(2z)+ 2\cosh(4z) - \cosh(6z)\right) \, dz \\
&= 14z + \frac{17}2 \sinh(2z) + \frac12 \sinh(4z) - \frac16 \sinh(6z) \bigg\rvert_{z=\operatorname{arsinh}1} \\
&= \frac{34\sqrt2}3 + 14 \operatorname{arsinh}1
\end{align*}$$
